# Webpack - TypeError: this[NS] is not a function at childCompiler.runAsChild

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack.config.js

I'm working currently with Webpack in server-side-rendering style. When trying to implement CSS support for my bundles I get this error in bundle-time :

> Webpack - TypeError: this[NS] is not a function at
>   childCompiler.runAsChild

Here my webpack.config.js :

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals'); 
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

// BrowserConfig  
const browserConfig =  {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: "./src/client/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
        }
      },{
      test:/\.css$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      include: /(src)/,
      use:  [ "style-loader",MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/], 
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "public/css/[name].css"
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "true"
    })
  ]
};


// ServerConfig 

const serverConfig = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: "./src/server/index.js",
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  target: "node",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "server.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  }, 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        options: {
          name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
        }
      },{
      test:/\.css$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      include: /(src)/,
      use:  [ "style-loader",MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader/locals', 'postcss-loader']
      },
      {
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/], 
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "public/css/[name].css"
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __isBrowser__: "false"
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig];
```

I can't figure out what is wrong since it seems to me I have include all necessary instructions in my program.

If someone have any hint, would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I’m getting the same thing, with Vue. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1775  Check the other issue I link to for MiniCssExtractPlugin. There’s a lot of people getting this when they use the loader but don’t add it to the plugins array, or vice versa, but looks like that’s not the issue for you. And I don’t think that’s the issue with the Vue CLI either... so no ideas yet.

Comment: thanks for the hint Chase, so nobody know what is going on here :/ ?  Maybe there is other Css bundlers to find on npm ? I will get an eye

Comment: I went out of town soon after my last comment, and worked on an old laptop I haven't deved on in ages. First I ran updates on node and various global packages. And then wouldn't' ya know it... hit the same error. There must be some ambiguous issue deep down that's causing a conflict. So I went nuclear and just reformatted everything. Reformatting is a terrible solution, but I followed this guide from a fellow Windows dev, and now my whole dev environment seems better for it. No more errors: https://daverupert.com/2018/04/developing-on-windows-with-wsl-and-visual-studio-code/